# Grails multi-project build using a single, embedded Tomcat server

Tags: gradle, grails

I have a couple Grails 5 applications that I'd like to combine using the multi-project build functionality of Gradle.  Each existing Grails application would become a sub-project within the multi-project build.  An embedded Tomcat server is currently used in the deployments of each of the two separate applications.  I have most of the multi-project solution figured out, but I'm looking for help/advice on the embedded Tomcat server requirement.  Is there a way to have a single Tomcat server embedded in a multi-project build so that all of the sub-project applications run on that shared server using the same port?